# Android(ReactNative) Open deep link from `adb shell am start` does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, deep-linking

I want to set up deep link in Android using React Native.
I set AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
        <!-- Settings for deep link below -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="lucmo-client-app" android:host="lucmo-client-app" />
</intent-filter>
```

I set up urls using this library: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

When I execute

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d lucmo-client-app://lucmo-client-app/users/1 com.lucmo_client_app
```

It says

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=lucmo-client-app://lucmo-client-app?data=1 pkg=com.lucmo_client_app }

Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=lucmo-client-app://lucmo-client-app?data=1 flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.lucmo_client_app }
```

On the other hand, it works fine when setting up in `Run > Edit Configurations` in Android Studio.

[image]

What is wrong about this?